# keeping highcharts stacked columns borderWdith but removing stacking gap

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts

How do I keep the highcharts columns borderWidth as 1px yet remove the stacked border width?[image]

```
plotOptions: {

        series: {
            pointPadding: 0,
            groupPadding: 0,
            borderWidth: 1
        },
        column: {
            stacking: 'normal',
            borderWidth: 0 // this will not work
        }
    },
```

Comment: I would just remove the border and adjust the `pointPadding`

Answer (score 0):

You can keep borderWidth equaled 0 and add white plot lines which will separate the columns.

```
xAxis: {
        categories: ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Grapes', 'Bananas'],
        plotLines: [{
            value: 0.5,
          width: 1,
          color: 'white',
          zIndex: 5
        },
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/v6fwwLkq/

The downside of the solution is that it covers horizontal grid lines (creates 1 px space). If it concerns you then plot lines height can be changed (needs wrapping Highcharts code) or custom vertical lines with the proper height can be added instead.